# Java JTable Resize Row

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable, row

Is it possible by default to resize a JTable row in the same way you can resize a column by dragging the mouse at the header?  If so, how can you do this?

Comment: you mean a bit like the UI component called *"nested grid"* (that Swing doesn't have btw)?  AFAIK no, you can't resize rows.  All rows have the same height and you can't allow the user to easily resize row height using JTable.

Comment: Thanks; I'll wait for more answers and hopefully someone with either agree or have a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it:
http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/make_jtable_resiable_better_than

It is more than you need but it is a good starting point if you really need a row header. Otherwise you can use it as it is.